# Django Choices Not Being DIsplayed

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

Good day,
I am trying to create a django model that contains a choice whether the user has read or not read a book. For that I have made a choice list. But i am unable to display it on the admin panel. All other fields are getting displayed other than the choice field.
Can you please tell me where  I am going wrong. I am new to django and have referred from the documnetation.
Following is the code:

```
class Book(models.Model):

YES = 'y'
NO = 'n'

DID_READ_CHOICES = [
    (YES,'Yes'),
    (NO,'No'),
]

title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
author = models.ForeignKey(
    Author,
    on_delete=models.SET_NULL, 
    null=True,
    related_name='author_books'
    )
genre = models.ManyToManyField(Genre, help_text='Select a genre for this book')
summary = models.TextField(max_length=1000, help_text='Enter a brief description of the book',blank=True,null=True)
read = models.CharField(
    max_length=1,
    choices=DID_READ_CHOICES,
    default=NO,
    ),

objects = BookManager()

class Meta:
    ordering = ['title']

def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

Thank you

Comment: You have a trailing comma at the end of `read`, so you wrap it in a singleton tuple, and thus Django did not detect that field. The presence of `choices` has *nothing* to do with it.

Comment: Thank you, I was stuck in this for half an hour.

Answer (score 0):

There is a trailing question at the end of read, thus django did not detect the field.